# Decode xor data in IDA

Tags: ida, deobfuscation, xor

I have code that looks like this:

```
byte_100031BA4 = v41;
byte_100031BA5 ^= 0x3Eu;
byte_100031BA6 ^= 0x47u;
LOBYTE(a1) = -9;
byte_100031BA7 ^= 0xF7u;
byte_100031BA8 ^= 0xA9u;
byte_100031BA9 ^= 0xE8u;
byte_100031BAA ^= 0x5Eu;
byte_100031BAB ^= 0x7Fu;
byte_100031BAC ^= 0x33u;
LOBYTE(a2) = 116;
byte_100031BAD ^= 0x74u;
byte_100031BAE ^= 0x78u;
byte_100031BAF ^= 0xFAu;
xmmword_100031B80 = (__int128)_mm_xor_ps((__m128)xmmword_100031B80, (__m128)xmmword_10002E1C0);
byte_100031B90 ^= 0x8Bu;
byte_100031B92 ^= 0xD5u;
byte_100031B93 ^= 0x53u;
byte_100031B94 ^= 0x9Bu;
byte_100031B95 ^= 0x16u;
byte_100031B96 ^= 0x18u;
```

I want to use IDA Python to run on each line of code and if it starts with 'byte_' and has '^=' in it then do for me the or and show the 'decrypted value' in a comment.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

the output you posted doesn't seem to be disassembly but PseudoCode
I am not sure if you want your pseudo Code Commented or Disassembly Commented
below is an approach to Comment the Disassembly using the built-in idc on Ida Free 7

iirc you can run idc from python (ida free doesn't support either pseudo code or python so I cant be sure )

the disassembly look like this prior to using the script

```
.data:0000000140023898 byte_140023898  db 0
.data:0000000140023899 byte_140023899  db 0
.data:000000014002389A byte_14002389A  db 0
```

script is along these lines entered an executed using shift+f2 or file->scriptCommand

```
auto addr,byteat,xorred;
addr = ask_addr(0,"enter an Address");
Message("you entered %x\n",addr);
byteat = get_db_byte(addr);
Message("byte at Address is %x\n",byteat);
Message("xorring byte with 0x3E\n");
xorred = byteat ^ 0x3e;
Message("result of xor = %x\n" , xorred);
Message("Setting Comment\n");
set_cmt(addr,sprintf("xorred result is %x\n",xorred),0);
```

after execution these messages will be seen in the Output Window

```
you entered 140023898
byte at Address is 0
xorring byte with 0x3E
result of xor = 3e
Setting Comment
```

and the commented disassembly will look like

```
.data:0000000140023898 byte_140023898  db 0                    ; xorred result is 3e
.data:0000000140023898                                         ;
.data:0000000140023899 byte_140023899  db 0
.data:000000014002389A byte_14002389A  db 0
```

Answer (score 0):

A decompiler plugin can be made to apply xor operations automatically. Please check [this blog post](https://www.hex-rays.com/blog/deobfucsating-xored-strings/) for more info and sample code.